# C# type inference, generics and interfaces

Tags: c#

I found something strange for me in type inference in C#.

The example.

I've got an interface

```
interface IInterface1
{
}
```

and a class that implements the interface

```
class Class1 : IInterface1
{
}
```

Then I have a function that creates the class

```
static Class1 GetInstanceOfClass1()
{
    return new Class1();
}
```

And I want to use generic function that will return an enumerable

```
static IEnumerable<T> GetSomething<T>() where T : IInterface1
{
    yield return GetInstanceOfClass1();
}
```

The full code is

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TypeInference
{
    interface IInterface1
    {
    }

    class Class1 : IInterface1
    {
    }

    class Program
    {
        static Class1 GetInstanceOfClass1()
        {
            return new Class1();
        }

        static IEnumerable<T> GetSomething<T>() where T : IInterface1
        {
            yield return GetInstanceOfClass1();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

This code is not compiled

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'TypeInference.Class1' to 'T'

If i write as

```
yield return (T)GetInstanceOfClass1();
```

the error message is as

> Cannot convert type 'TypeInference.Class1' to 'T'

it cannot convert as before.

Ok. I write as

```
yield return (IInterface1)GetInstanceOfClass1();
```

and got

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'TypeInference.IInterface1' to 'T'

it cannot convert as before.

But if I write as

```
yield return (T)(IInterface1)GetInstanceOfClass1();
```

everything is ok.

Can someone explain me what was wrong and why the code eventually is compiled?

Thank you.

Comment: there is no guarantee that `(T)(IInterface1)GetInstanceOfClass1();` won't break at runtime. One can create `class NewClass1 : IInterface1`; call `GetSomething<NewClass1>()` and get exception. Compiler *trusts* you when you do a type cast `(T)(IInterface1)`, but the runtime won't

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's to prevent yourself from shooting yourself in the foot. Like you managed to end up doing anyway.

What happens if you define

```
interface IInterface2 : IInterface1 { }
```

and then call `GetSomething<IInterface2>()`? It's a valid generic type argument, but `Class1` doesn't implement `IInterface2`.

Worse yet, what happens if you define

```
class Class2 : IInterface1 { }
```

and then call `GetSomething<Class2>()`?

Your design is broken, you need to think about it some more, and not continue working around the compiler errors until you have a design that actually has a chance of working.

Answer (score 3):

Your type parameter T is guaranteed to implement `IInterface1`, but its relation with `Class1` is unspecified.

Thus:

1. T might not be a super class of `Class1` and also `Class1` might not be a super class of T => `(T)GetInstanceOfClass1()` fails
2. You can't return an `IInterface` from a method that returns T => `(IInterface1)GetInstanceOfClass1()` fails

The one that works:

You can of course cast `Class1` to `IInterface` because `Class1` implements the interface.
Now since T also implements IInterface it could be a valid cast or it could fail at runtime.
This is similar to how you can convert any object to a given type at compile time, but if the runtime type of the object is wrong it would fail at run time.

E.g.

```
object o;
o = 5;
string s = (string)o;
```

This  compiles, but fails at run time.